# .net 6 blazor wasm hot reload not working

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and created a new Blazor webassembly app and ran it.
The option for hot reload on file save is checked.

If I make changes in the Counter component (either HTML or C# code changes) and save the file I see a tick symbol appear at the top left of the browser but neither of the changes have kicked in, the browser just continues with the old version.
[image]

After the change the counter still increments even though I changed it to decrement and the h1 title doesnt include the 2 after it.

Answer (score 11):

So i've worked out that it only works if you run the project without debugging, not with debugging.

Ctrl + F5 (hot reload works), F5 (doesn't work)

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly Hot Reload not supported in debug mode yet. According to [this update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/update-on-net-hot-reload-progress-and-visual-studio-2022-highlights/#when-using-visual-studio-2022-with-a-net-6-app-the-most-type-of-scenarios-are-supported) they're "working to resolve this in the next Visual Studio update".

Comment: Seems like CLI is the way to go for now. Issue the command ```dotnet watch --project .\my-wasm.csproj```. [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38202)

Comment: It is supported while debugging now.

Answer (score 5):

Just try restarting Visual Studio, if it suddenly stops working.

Comment: It has often worked that way for me

Comment: Man that's really annoying, but yes it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm what The Thirsty Ape suggested works when running Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6

```
dotnet watch --project .\your-project-name-here.csproj
```

The browser will launch and the console should display something like:

```
watch : Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload. Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
```

And finally after making a code change:

```
watch : Hot reload of changes succeeded.
```

**No refresh is required**

Answer (score 3):

On Blazor Icon (Next to debug icon) click on hot reload on file save, it should work now.

[image: the red icon like firefox icon]

Answer (score 1):

I was using the visual studio IDE 2022 **v17.0.1**

**Updated** the visual studio IDE 2022 to **v17.1.2** supported the blazor hot reload

[image]

**Note: Help -> Check for updates**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Hot Reload works only in certain configurations:

- When I host the app in **IIS Express** - hot reload **works**, even in
  Debug mode.
- When I host the app in **Docker**, hot reload **does** **NOT** **work** neither
  with or without debugger.

I had tested in Visual Studio v17.2.2 (although v17.1.2 should be sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that "hot reload on file save" is actually on if like me that's what you rely on.

It can be found in the menu on the flame icon.

I somehow managed to turn that off without knowing and didn't even realize there was a hot reload button.